# Difference of double subscript overloading between using vector and pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload [][] by using vector and pointer. Actually, I successfully code them up. But I got a little confuse about the vector version. Please refer my implementation as following:

This is the pointer version:

```
class Array2 {
    private:
    unsigned row, col;
    int** arr;
    public:
    Array2(unsigned r=0, unsigned c=0): row(r), col(c) {
        if(row * col != 0) {
            arr = new int*[row];
            for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                arr[i] = new int[col];
            }
        }
    }

    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(int* _array) : _array(_array) { }
        int& operator[](int index) {
            return _array[index];
        }
    private:
        int* _array;
    };

    Proxy operator [] (int index) {
        return Proxy(arr[index]);
    }
}
```

This is the vector version:

```
class Array2 {
    private:
        unsigned row, col;
        vector<vector<int> > arr;
    public:
        Array2(unsigned r=0, unsigned c=0)
            : row(r), col(c), arr(r, vector<int>(c)) { }

    vector<int>& operator [] (int index) {
        return arr[index];
    }
}
```

This is the **fail** vector version:

```
class Array2 {
    private:
        unsigned row, col;
        vector<vector<int> > arr;
    public:
        Array2(unsigned r=0, unsigned c=0)
            : row(r), col(c), arr(r, vector<int>(c)) { }

    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(vector<int> _array) : _array(_array) { }

        int& operator[](int index) {
            return _array[index];
        }
    private:
        vector<int> _array;
    };

    Proxy operator [] (int index) {
        return Proxy(arr[index]);
    }
}
```

With the fail version, I cannot successfully assign value to the vector using operation such as `arr[2][3] = 23`. Can anyone tell me what I misunderstand in the fail vector version?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The proxy makes a copy, you instead should have it use references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Proxy(vector<int> _array) : _array(_array) { }`, `vector` is copied. That means `_array` inside `Proxy` has nothing to do with the original `vector` (i.e. `arr[index]` when `return Proxy(arr[index]);`)

You might save a pointer to `vector`. Such as:

```
class Proxy {
public:
    Proxy(vector<int>& _array) : p(&_array) {}
    int& operator[](int index) {
        return (*p)[index];
    }
private:
    vector<int>* p;
};
```

Of course, your successful vector version would be better.